# NIC not connecting without default gatway

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2019

I have replaced an end-of-life server in a hosting center, with a new one running Windows Server 2019.   The old and new servers were/are multi-homed.   I have simply reused the network cables and assigned the same IP settings on the new server as were on the old (Windows Server 2003)

I cannot connect to one of the NICs and it shows 'Unidentified network' (and 'no network access' in the status screen)

If I add in the default gateway for that server it begins to work, but I get a warning from the OS

> Warning - Multiple default gateways are intended to provide redundancy
>   to a single network (such as an intranet or the Internet). They will
>   not function properly when the gateways are on two separate, disjoint
>   networks (such as one on your intranet and one on the Internet). Do
>   you want to save this configuration?

(The other NIC is configured on a different vlan, has its own default gateway, and works fine)

The old server (and other 2003 server due to be replaced) worked fine without a default gateway entered.  Is there something extra required in Windows Server 2019 to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by adding a route.

The problematic network is a management network (intended for remoting into the server) and I am connecting from a 192.168.0.0 network...

```
route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0  192.168.202.1 METRIC 1 -p
```

As soon as I did that, I was able to Remotely connect to the server on that NIC (I had previously been using the other NIC's IP address, which isn't intended for that purpose)